# Busqueda de subcadena en cadena con metodo charAt()

Tags: java, string

podrían ayudarme con este ejercicio, pide realizar una búsqueda de subcadena en otra cadena , y si esta subcadena esta contenida en la cadena principal retorna true, el problema seria que me pide utilizar solamente charAt() para el caso.

Espero puedan ayudarme!

```
public class busquedaArreglo {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a= "My yellow";
        String b= "My";
        int cont=0;
        boolean afirmativo= true;
        for(int dos=0; dos<a.length();dos++){  
            //for(int uno=0; uno<a.length(); uno++){ // recorre la cadena mas grande           
                if(a.charAt(dos)==b.charAt(dos)){
                    cont=cont++;                  
                }
            //}
        }
   
       if(cont==1){
           System.out.println(afirmativo);
       }
       else{
           System.out.println("No contien a la subcadena");
       }           
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo bastante simple.

Piensa en una variable que lleve la cuenta de cuántas letras han coincidido, si en un momento llega a pasar que la cuenta es igual a la longitud de la subcadena a buscar, entonces ya sabes que existe.

```java
public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int counter = 0;
        String phrase = "The kitty jumped";
        String search = "kitty";

        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            // Si el carácter en i coincide con el carácter de la cuenta
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == search.charAt(counter)) {
                // Se aumenta en 1 y si el contador es igual
                // a la longitud de la cuenta, entonces se rompe
                // el ciclo, pues ya fue hallada la subcadena
                if (++counter >= search.length())
                    break;
            } else {
                // Se le resta la cantidad de letras que llevaba el
                // contador para probar otra vez en casos como:
                // phrase = "The kitty jumped" && search = "ty jum"
                // De lo contrario la primera t coincide (t con t), pero la segunda sería (t con y) y se continuaría diciendo que no existe aunque sí exista
                i -= counter;
                // Se reinicia el contador, pues ya no hay coincidencia
                counter = 0;
            }
        }

        // Se halló coincidencia
        if (counter == search.length()) {
            System.out.println("\"" + search + "\" was found inside the string \"" + phrase + "\"");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not coincidences found for \"" + search + "\"");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A ver si te sirve

Yo lo que hago es pedir la frase y la cadena a buscar que como máximo tenga 4 caracteres

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //instlaciamos la clase escanner
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    /pedimos la frase y la recogemos en la variable
    System.out.println("Ponga una palabra o una frase: ");
    String frase = teclado.nextLine();
    
    /pedimos la cadena y la recogemos en la variable
    System.out.println("Ponga la cadena a buscar en la frase: (Máximo 4 caracteres)");
    String caracteres = teclado.nextLine();
    
    /contamos los caracteres de la frase y de la cadena y los almacenamos en las variables
    int nFrase = frase.length();
    int nCaracteres = caracteres.length();
    
    //variable booleana a false
    boolean contiene = false;

    //si los caracteres son mayor a 0 y menor que la frase con el máximo de 4
    if (nCaracteres > 0) && (nCaracteres < nFrase) && (nCaracteres <= 4)){
        //según el número del número de caracteres
        switch (nCaracteres){
            case 1:
                //bucle que recorre la frase
                for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++){  
                    //si el carácter se encuentra en la frase en el lugar de la iteracion del bucle     
                    if (frase.charAt(i) == caracteres.charAt(i)) {
                        //ponemos la variable a true
                        contiene = true;                  
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                //bucle que recorre la frase
                for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++){
                    //si coinciden los dos caracteres de las posiciones 0 y 1 con caracteres de la frase según la iteración del bule            
                    if ((frase.charAt(i) == caracteres.charAt(0)) && (frase.charAt(i + 1) == caracteres.charAt(1))) {
                        //ponemos la variable a true
                        contiene = true;                  
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++){          
                    if ((frase.charAt(i) == caracteres.charAt(0)) && (frase.charAt(i + 1) == caracteres.charAt(1)) && (frase.charAt(i + 2) == caracteres.charAt(2))) {
                        contiene = true;                  
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++){          
                    if ((frase.charAt(i) == caracteres.charAt(0)) && (frase.charAt(i + 1) == caracteres.charAt(1)) && (frase.charAt(i + 2) == caracteres.charAt(2)) && (frase.charAt(i + 3) == caracteres.charAt(3))) {
                        contiene = true;                  
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    
   //si la variable está a true
   if(contiene){
       //imprimimos el resultado
       System.out.println("La cadena " + caracteres + " se encuentra contenida en la frase");
   }
   /si no
   else{
       //informamos
       System.out.println("No contien a la subcadena");
   }           
}
```

Comment: Me puede explicar, quien haya sido, el motivo de porqué votó mi respuesta en negativo ?

Comment: En mi caso, creo que es una solución inadecuada, pues complica el problema y tiene una gran limitación. La solución solamente realmente puede ser mucho más sencilla y sin las limitantes

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy buena, la verdad. Pero la gracia de la programación, es que cada uno lo interpreta a su forma de ver, y aunque se intente buscar el método lo más práctico y eficaz posible, a veces los conocimientos de uno no llegan a tanto, y dar con la solución a mi forma de entender ya es meritorio y nunca merecería un negativo. Puede no ser sobresaliente, pero tampoco muy deficiente si se consigue solucionar el problema. Mejor solucionarlo que dejarlo por imposible.

Comment: En realidad a mí no me gusta hacer votos negativos, pero una vez leí en una pregunta en meta que votando lo más posible ayudas a la comunidad a tener una mejor organización de la calidad de preguntas y respuestas. Citando el artículo sobre [votar negativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down): "La emisión de votos negativos, también conocida como ''votar en contra'', es la forma en la que la comunidad indica qué preguntas y respuestas son menos útiles."

Comment: No no, si yo no estoy en contra de los votos negativos, al contrario, como tu muy bien dices, sirven para seleccionar a unos y aleccionarse a otros. En mi comentario, simplemente pedía explicación a quien había votado negativo a mi respuesta, de porque lo había hecho. Y como digo, no por haberlo hecho en sí, sino el motivo, que es lo que me interesa de verdad, pues si comento errores, me gustaría saber cuales son para intentar corregirlos.

Comment: Claro, una manera igual de "remover" los votos negativos, es editando tu respuesta para mejorar su contenido. Realmente si al editar tu respuesta llegas a una mejor solución, contarás con mi voto positivo ;D

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129048/discussion-between-el-trasgu-and-eduardo-jimenez).

Comment: @EduardoJiménez, como poco, extraño resulta que votes negativo una solución que funciona, y no otra que no funciona.

Comment: Pues siento no estar de acuerdo contigo @EduardoJiménez, estás dando la impresión de que quieres que tu respuesta sea la única buena votando negativo a las demás aún siendo tan válidas como la tuya. Es más, me fijo en que tu respuesta tiene comentarios en inglés, por lo que deduzco que simplemente la buscaste por internet y la pegaste como respuesta. Sin embargo la otra es más abierta, pues coge cualquier texto metido por teclado y no el que le tengas que meter por código, además parte del código del OP. Creo que te has columpiado. Es mi opinión. Un saludo

Comment: @Vanessa Yo creo todas mis respuestas, y estoy acostumbrado a programar en inglés, pues es el idioma estándar y que preferentemente se debe usar. Por lo cual te puedo asegurar que si hay comentarios en inglés no son porque los haya copiado, puedes revisar las otras respuestas que he publicado y verás que la gran mayoría están escritas en inglés. Por parte de no usar el código de la pregunta es por dos razones: 1.- La pregunta es acerca de hallar subcadenas, no de cómo leer cadenas, por lo que quitar el Scanner ahorra tiempo de lectura para la respuesta.

Comment: @Vanessa 2.- Muchas veces es más fácil crear tu propio código que editar el de la pregunta. Por parte de la impresión que te doy, ya expuse la razón de porqué voté negativo en esta respuesta, créeme que no votas negativo por placer, de hecho es un arma de doble filo, pues tanto a quien votas negativo como al que vota les quita reputación

Comment: @Vanessa, En [esta publicación en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5185/por-qu%c3%a9-se-usan-tan-poco-los-votos-en-la-valoraci%c3%b3n-de-preguntas-y-respuestas) que tú misma formulaste preguntas porqué se vota tan poco en preguntas y respuestas. Por lo que me parece contradictorio que critiques a alguien que está tratando de votar más activamente. Recuerda que los votos son positivos y negativos.

Comment: Buen debate. Creo que lo que tratan de explicar, @EduardoJiménez, es que mientras DevMind tiene cero votos y su respuesta como tu muy bien has indicado no funciona (O sea, nadie le ha votado en contra, ni siquiera tú), la respuesta de Trasgu, que si funciona y si resulta funcional, ha recibido tu voto negativo, por lo que he podido intuir en tu comentario, ya que ahora no tiene negativos. Y la gente se extraña, también yo, porque algo válido es votado de forma negativa, y algo que no lo es, no es votado negativo. Luego puedes dar las explicaciones que quieras, pero la realidad es esa.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que controlar romper el ciclo `for`, si no te saltara error `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`

Después en la comprobación del  `if(cont==1){` debe ser 2 porque el método `charAt()` cuenta por caracteres y tu necesitas en este caso 2.

Te dejo ejemplo completo para que lo veas como quedaria:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    String a = "My yellow";
    String b = "My";
    int cont =0;
    boolean afirmativo = true;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length();i++){  //recorremos la cadena mayor
        
       if(b.length() == i)break; //cuando el valor de la i llegue al tamaño de la segunda cadena rompemos el ciclo y evitamos el error
   
       if(b.charAt(i) == a.charAt(i)){ // comparamos carácter a carácter las dos cadenas y sumamos la cantidad de coincidencias
          cont++;
       }
   }

    if(cont == b.length()){ //si el contador equivale al tamaño de la cadena a buscar, mostraremos true
        System.out.println(afirmativo);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No contiene a la subcadena");
    }
}
```

Espero que te pueda servir y no dudes en preguntar cualquier duda.

Comment: No funciona correctamente

Comment: Prueba buscando la subcadena "yellow", nunca va a encontrar otra subcadena más que la del inicio.

Comment: @EduardoJiménez tienes razón. Muy bueno tu ejemplo :)