# Programa que me compara si un array esta dentro del otro, el problema es que cuando se repite un numero en cualquier array falla

Tags: java

He hecho un programa que me compara si un array (el chico) esta dentro del otro (grande), el problema es que cuando se repite un numero en cualquier array falla porque cuenta el repetido como un aumento de posición y si llega al máximo las demás no las hace.

Este es el código:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BuscarArrayEnOtro {

public static char[] A= {2, 2, 10, 4, 5, 10}; //aqui al repetirse 2 numeros falla 
    public static char[] B= {2, 9, 10};
    //Método buscar array en otro
    public static void Buscararray() {
        try {
            int pos=0;
            for (int i=0; i<B.length; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j < A.length; j++) {
                    if (B[i]==A[j]) {
                        pos++;
                    }
            }
            }
        if (pos>=B.length) {
            System.out.println("El array B está en el array A");
        }else {
            System.out.println("El array B no esta en el A");
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error en los arrays");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Buscararray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Checa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/479869/busqueda-de-subcadena-en-cadena-con-metodo-charat/479893#479893) es con cadenas de texto, pero el principio es el mismo

Comment: poner un `break;` después de `pos++;` te puede servir

Comment: Al decir  ``si un array esta dentro del otro`` te refieres que uno de los elementos del array B se encuentra dentro del array A o todo el array B tiene que pertenecer al array A como si se tratara de una sub cadena

Comment: el break lo he probado y funcionaba pero no con todas las posibilidades

Comment: todo el array pequeño dentro del grande aunque en el grande haya mas numeros

Comment: también he probado a decrementar el pos pero funciona como el break depende de la situación

Comment: La respuesta es simple que no pondré una respuesta, pon un ``break;`` después de ``pos++;``

Answer (score 1):

He puesto un break; debajo de pos++; y va perfecto.

```
public class Prueba {
    public static char[] A= {2, 2, 10, 4, 5, 10}; //aqui al repetirse 2 numeros falla 
    public static char[] B= {2, 9, 10};
    //Método buscar array en otro
    public static void Buscararray() {
        try {
            int pos=0;
            for (int i=0; i<B.length; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j < A.length; j++) {
                    if (B[i]==A[j]) {
                        pos++;
                        break; // TE FALTA ESTE break;
                    }
            }
            }
        if (pos>=B.length) {
            System.out.println("El array B está en el array A");
        }else {
            System.out.println("El array B no esta en el A");
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error en los arrays");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Buscararray();
    }
}
```